# How add captcha without php?

Tags: javascript, html, captcha

This my code: the function `check()` is working, but the function `ChangeCaptcha()` didn't show letter in input `type="randomfield"` :

```
<body onload="ChangeCaptcha()">
  <input type="text" id="randomfield" disabled><br><br>                               
    <input id="CaptchaEnter" size="20" ><br><br>                         
    <button type="submit" onclick="check()">Log in</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeCaptcha() {
      var chars= "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var string_lenght = 6;
      var ChangeCaptcha = '';
      for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        ChangeCaptcha+= chars.substring(rnum, rnum+1);
      }
      document.getElementById('randomfield').value= ChangeCaptcha;
    }
    function check() {
      if (document.getElementById('CaptchaEnter').value == document.getElementById('randomfield').value) {
        window.open('http://www.lolila.hol.es', '_self');
      } else {
        alert('Pleace re-check the captcha!')
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Why would you do Client-side captcha validation? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196335/how-to-create-simple-javascript-jquery-client-side-captcha

Comment: Typo on `var string_lenght = 6` >> `i<string_length;` Open your browser console to view error reports.

Comment: string_length is wrongly typed in assigning variable; change it and run

Comment: in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: string_length is not defined
ChangeCaptcha @ index.html:39
onload @ index.html:26
and in input type="randomfield" didn't show letter (captcha code)

Comment: @NazarVovk As I have clearly pointed out, you have a typo. This is why `string_length` isn't defined. You have defined `string_lenght` **Not** `string_length`

Comment: IT work ))) thank you guys

Comment: @NazarVovk Very welcome, simple typo. Your browser console is you best friend!

Answer (score 1):

I executed your code right here in chrome developer console:
[image]

it tells me you have a typo in your code because i does not know the variable: `string_length`. you declared it as `string_lenght`. To fix, change string_lenght => string_length.

The result:

```
function ChangeCaptcha() {
      var chars= "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var string_length = 6;
      var ChangeCaptcha = '';
      for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        ChangeCaptcha+= chars.substring(rnum, rnum+1);
      }
      document.getElementById('randomfield').value= ChangeCaptcha;
    }
```

the result:
[image]